# Как сделать лямбду explicit

Tags: c++

```
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>

template <class... Ts>
struct MakeVisitor : Ts... {
  using Ts::operator()...;
};

template <class... Ts>
MakeVisitor(Ts ...) -> MakeVisitor<Ts...>;

template <class... Ty>
using Channel = std::variant<Ty...>;

decltype(auto) f(Channel<int, double, char> channel){
  MakeVisitor visitor(
      [](int val) { return 1; }, 
   // [](char val) { return 1; }, реализации для char нет, но все компилируется
      [](double val)  { return 1; });

  return std::visit(visitor, channel);
}

int main(){

    f(1);
    f(2.5);
    f('a'); // Не должно работать

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: visitor для `variant<int, double, char>` *должен* работать со всеми типами из варианта. В данном случае char преобразуется в int. Если бы это неявное преобразование было невозможно, то и пример бы все равно не собрался

Comment: А что делать, если в variant 20 типов, а функция работает только с 2-3 из них?

Comment: Тогда visitor должен будет уметь работать со всеми 20. ¿Или у вас вопрос наоборот в том, как сделать так, чтобы оно не собиралось, если нет явного обработчика для каждого из 20 типов?

Comment: да, у меня вопрос наоборот

Comment: так как вы передаёте аргументом временный объект *(lvalue)*, и даёте аргументом встроенный тип `char`, то происходит тихое преобразование типа `char`->`int`. Не пользуйтесь простыми типами, а только своими классами с запретом преобразования типов.

Answer (score 4):

Если в класс визитора добавить, дополнительные операторы () для этих типов, то будут выбираться именно эти операторы, а не неявное преобразование типов.

```
template <class... Ts>
struct MakeVisitorExplicit : Ts... {
  MakeVisitorExplicit(Ts...args) : Ts(args)... {}
  using Ts::operator()...;

//private: // Можно объявить private или deleted, но сообщение об ошибке будет еще менее читабельным
  template<typename T>
  auto operator() (T) const
  {
      static_assert( false, "Access to usupported type" );
      return throw std::runtime_error("Access to usupported type");
  }
};
```